# Hover on button shows different text that isn't as wide. How to prevent changing button width?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering how i can have a button retain its width on hover. I want to use css for the transitions as opposed to a jQuery solution.

So how do I do this? I'd love it if there were a pure css implementation but I'll settle for jQuery if I have to.

Edit: min-width won't work since the button text is dynamic.

Here's a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/b1kbsqt1/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('button')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).find('.btn-text').toggleClass('hidden');
      $(this).find('.options').toggleClass('hidden');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).find('.btn-text').toggleClass('hidden');
      $(this).find('.options').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, green 50%, white 50%);
}
button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
.options {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">
  <span class="btn-text">Button Thing</span>
  <span class="options hidden">Go</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a CSS solution, since my jQuery solution didn't work correctly.

I changed the .hidden class to use opacity and then absolutely positioned the option text. This will only work if the option text is always shorter than the initial text, of course.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1kbsqt1/4/)

```
button{
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, green 50%, white 50%);
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
.options{
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you! I hadn't considered this at all!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would probably be to add the following jQuery, where you add an inline width to the button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button')
    var width = $(this).width();
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).css('width',width);
      $(this).find('.btn-text').toggleClass('hidden');
      $(this).find('.options').toggleClass('hidden');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).find('.btn-text').toggleClass('hidden');
      $(this).find('.options').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, green 50%, white 50%);
}
button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
.options {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

}
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">
  <span class="btn-text">Button Thing</span>
  <span class="options hidden">Go</span>
</button>
```

Comment: You're jQuery isn't even close to being correct. It would fail over and over. Why would anyone up vote this?

Comment: How exactly would this fail? It just sets an inline width on hover to retain the current width. Although if the hidden button text is wider than the current text, I can see where there would be an issue. Is that what you mean?

Comment: For real? You think this would work?
`$('button')var width = $(this).width();.on('mouseover', function() { ... }`
Regardless, I see what you're thinking... CSS hover happens before jQuery can get ahold of the original width.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did and you're absolutely right - sorry about that. I think a CSS solution might be best after all. I added one as a new answer...

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the width: `width:25%;` in .button

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1kbsqt1/1/)

```
.button{
 height: 60px;
 padding: 0 25px;
 line-height: 60px;
 background-size: 100% 200%;
 transition: all 0.1s;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, green 50%, white 50%);
  width:25%;
}
```

Comment: This isn't scalable at all. The answer shouldn't be dependent upon the buttons parent width.